# SQL BETWEEN Operator conditional value in Reverse Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why the following SQL query show results?

```
     SELECT * FROM Products
     WHERE Price BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```

but when we change the order of value it will not show any result?

```
     SELECT * FROM Products
     WHERE Price BETWEEN 20 AND 10;
```

Comment: @MinhD: Have a look at the question's tags.

Comment: Actually, this question has the same answer for any DBMS.

Comment: @stakx: Actually, the question didn't have any tag at first sight :)

Answer (score 5):

```
 SELECT * FROM Products
 WHERE Price BETWEEN 20 AND 10;
```

translates to

```
 SELECT * FROM Products
 WHERE Price >= 20 AND Price <= 10;
```

Answer (score 5):

BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to the value of end_expression.
NOT BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is less than the value of begin_expression or greater than the value of end_expression.

In your case, your statement evaluates to 
`greater than or equal to 20  AND less than or equal to 10`

Answer (score 2):

Because order does matter. Come to think of it:

```
x BETWEEN a AND b
```

is equivalent to

```
a <= x AND x <= b
```

If `a > b`, this can never be true.

In other words, for `BETWEEN` to be of any use, you must ensure that `a <= b`.