# Why is SQL Server's Between not working when operands swap?

Tags: sql-server

Assume we have a table with an `int` column (primary key) and few other columns as well and above table contains data.

This query is working:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE Id BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

However, this query is not working:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE Id BETWEEN 5 AND 1
```

I need an explanation why inverse not working when I swap operands. Please explain.

Comment: With standard SQL you could use `between symmetric ...`  - don't know if SQL Server supports that though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23239619/5725863

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx): "BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to the value of end_expression."